# Php string date a date into another format?

Tags: php, date-format

Hi I want change date string -> `Sat Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2008` -> into `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` format my code is as below :

```
$lsd = strtotime($vehicle->newDate);
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$lsd);
```

I am getting date like `1970-01-01 05:30:00` Why is so ?

I have gone through reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

I have got date fromat representation labels for all except `GMT+05:30`

```
   Sat Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2008
   D    M   d   H:i:s            o
```

Instead of down-votes if that one label I get then I will be thankful then I will use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Why you add `."");` to `$vehicle->newDate`?

Comment: @Saty removed it was unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one.

```
$lsd = strtotime("Sat Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2008");
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$lsd);
echo $newDate;
```

Comment: $vehicle->newDate="Sat Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2008" then why my code is having problem ? Can you explain please

Comment: if you code pass invalid date, php date function will show you 1970-01-01 05:30:00.

Comment: after giving echo $vehicle->newDate has value = "Wed Dec 16 00:00:00 GMT 05:30 2015" but after $lsd = strtotime($vehicle->newDate); then echo $lsd doen't show anything, hence date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$lsd); might be returning the default (date from beginning).

Comment: $lsd = strtotime($vehicle->newDate); then echo $lsd doen't show anything,

that means that your $lsd variable is overwrite.

Comment: Problem was @server coz "Sat Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2008" was not url safe parameter hence while reading due to  '+' sign in "GMT+05:30" it was parsed as space like "Sat Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT 05:30 2008" hence strtotime() was failing,corrected from server started working thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$lsd = strtotime($vehicle->newDate);
$newDate = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
```

Comment: You might want to add `$lsd` to the `date()` function and what is `.""` supposed to achieve

Comment: Sorry buddy! i just pasted his code with some modification!